# How to display ProgressDialog bar within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to display a ProgressDialog during an AsyncTask, executed from a Fragment.
The problem I'm facing, it is that the progress dialog isn't displayed during the AsyncTask and I don't know why.

Here is the AsyncTask:

```
public class RankTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<RowRank>> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;

    public RankTask(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<RowRank> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        IDBInteraction interaction = new DBInteraction(
                Connection.getConnection());

        return interaction.getRank();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<RowRank> result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Here is the Fragment, which executes the AsyncTask:

```
public class RankFragment extends Fragment {

private TableLayout tableLayout;
private static float SIZE_TEXT = 20;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            com.example.testintro.R.layout.fragment_rank, container, false);
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.table_rank_layout);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.bringToFront();

    RankTask task = new RankTask(getActivity());
    try {

        createTable(task.execute().get());

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Here is the line of code of Activity, where the Fragment is commited:

```
private void changeActivity(Button button, final Fragment fragment) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: is there any error or something?

Comment: No error, just no Progress Dialog, but the object returned from the AsynctTask, it is correct and well working.

Comment: I guess the problem is `try catch` block. May be, you should put `try catch` inside `doInBackground`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I guess.. Its due to 'context' problem.. do passing context properly..**

> Added this code at your Fragment..

```
   public Context context;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context = activity;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to do with progress dialog or the fragment 
the only thing that is wrong in your could is that you are using

```
task.execute().get()
```

which will Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

and as it run on main thread you can't use any views remove the get() and it should works fine

Comment: Thank you. So what can I do to retrive the result from the AsyncTask ?

Comment: task.execute() and in doInBackground retrieve your data and in post execute use this data as you like to update your UI

Comment: If I try to write task.execute(); without the result, the progress dialog is show, but I have not the data. What do you mean with "in post execute use this data as you like to update your ui": How Can I pass the data to the activity, without the get() method ? I have this code: @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Report report) {
  this.dialog.dismiss();
  super.onPostExecute(report);
  
 }

Comment: I mean that you use the returned value of async task to do the followin createTable(task.execute().get());
so instead of that in your in post excute 
call the following 
createTable(report);
both are the same

Comment: So, you suggest me to create an Interface for the Fragment, with the method public void createTable(report) and in the onPostExecute() I invoke that method, isn't it ?

Comment: yes to do the same function you do in createTable(task.execute().get());
that way you get to keep your UI interactive

Comment: Good ! I think Android has some available feature to do that